How Can I Update User Profile Image using Graph API in C#
I want to update my user Profile image and another user's profile Image using Graph API in C#.
I have all permission in Microsoft Azure to do anything using code.
How can it be done?

Make sure to grant User.ReadWrite.All application type API permission:

To update the profile photo of a user, please use the below code:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace UserProperties
{
    public class GraphHandler
    {
        public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

        public GraphHandler()
        {
            var tenantId = "TenantID";
            var clientId = "ClientID";
            var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
            GraphClient = CreateGraphClient(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        }

        public GraphServiceClient CreateGraphClient(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = Azure.Identity.AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        }

        public async Task<bool> UpdateProfilePicture(string userId, string imagePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    await GraphClient.Users[userId].Photo.Content.PutAsync(stream);
                    Console.WriteLine("Profile picture updated successfully.");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error updating profile picture: {ex.Message}");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var handler = new GraphHandler();
            var userId = "UserID"; // Replace with the desired user's ID
            await handler.UpdateProfilePicture(userId, "C:\\Users\\rukmini\\Downloads\\ruk.jpg");
        }
    }
}


Profile photo updated successfully:


I am trying to update profile Photo using userPrincipalName instaed of userId, but that does not works.

What is the error ?

I am getting error like:  Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ImageNotFoundException' was thrown. - and Image Path is perfect but i don't know why it is throwing me this error.

Try any other image path as it is the error with Image not code

I tried, but that does not works. something is incorrect when they trying to update Image.

Does it work with UserID and not with UPN?

Yes, exactly, it is works with UserID but not with UPN

Can you post it as an new question I will check

I want to get all users using graph API but I am getting only top 100 users, i want to get all users, how can i do this.

Sure checking the new question you posted

If you get the error Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ImageNotFoundException when trying to update a user photo via Graph API (or Set-MgUserPhotoContent) make sure you use the UserID and not the UPN (UserPrincipalName) as parameter to identify the User.
For some reason, if the user does not have a mailbox, it only works with UserID. So better use UserID all the time.
