Which Permission is required for Creating a New User in Microsoft using Graph API in C#
I Have a all permission like User.ReadWrite.All , Directory.ReadWrite.All and this permission type is Application.
I think something is Permission issue in this case, I want to Create a New User using this c# code.
and I get this error when i was trying to create a new user: the expression cannot be evaluated. A common cause of this error is attempting to pass a lambda into a delegate.
public async Task createNewUser()
{
    try
    {
        var requestBody = new User
        {
            AccountEnabled = true,
            City = "Surat",
            Country = "India",
            Department = "IT",
            DisplayName = "Test User Unknown",
            GivenName = "Unknown",
            JobTitle = "SharePoint Developer",
            MailNickname = "UnknownT",
            PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration",
            PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
            {
                Password = "0296db04-e2c3-cbec-993b-663e59e50f1c",
                ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
            },
            OfficeLocation = "131/1105",
            PostalCode = "395010",
            PreferredLanguage = "en-US",
            State = "Gujarat",
            StreetAddress = "9256 Towne Center Dr., Suite 400",
            Surname = "Test",
            MobilePhone = "+91 1324567891",
            UsageLocation = "India",
            UserPrincipalName = "test.unknown@domain.com",
        };
        var result = await GraphClient.Users.PostAsync(requestBody);
        Console.WriteLine("User Created Successfully.");
    }
    catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error getting user details: {ex.Message}");
    }
}```


Can you give the full code? Are you using ClientSecretCredential?

@Rukmini, I am Using previous Question Code, that question link is [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78304277/how-can-i-update-user-profile-image-using-graph-api-in-c-sharp]

What is the error you are getting?

You are catching wrong exception. Try to catch Exception instead of ServiceException. The exception coming from Graph service is not handled properly. You should be able to see what's wrong with your request. At least UsageLocation should be two-letter code like IN.

To create user, make sure to grant User.ReadWrite.All application tpye API permission:

To create the user with the request body you provided, make use of below code:
UsageLocation must be IN not as India
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

namespace UserProperties
{
    public class GraphHandler
    {
        public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

        public GraphHandler(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            GraphClient = CreateGraphClient(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        }

        public GraphServiceClient CreateGraphClient(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = Azure.Identity.AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        }

        public async Task<bool> CreateUser(User user)
        {
            try
            {
                await GraphClient.Users.PostAsync(user);
                Console.WriteLine("User created successfully.");
                return true;
            }
            catch (ODataError odataError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"OData error details:");
                Console.WriteLine($"Code: {odataError.Error?.Code}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Message: {odataError.Error?.Message}");
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var tenantId = "TenantID";
                var clientId = "ClientID";
                var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
                var handler = new GraphHandler(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

                var requestBody = new User
                {
                    AccountEnabled = true,
                    City = "Surat",
                    Country = "India",
                    Department = "IT",
                    DisplayName = "Test User Unknown",
                    GivenName = "Unknown",
                    JobTitle = "SharePoint Developer",
                    MailNickname = "UnknownT",
                    PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration",
                    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                    {
                        Password = "***",
                        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
                    },
                    OfficeLocation = "131/1105",
                    PostalCode = "395010",
                    PreferredLanguage = "en-US",
                    State = "Gujarat",
                    StreetAddress = "9256 Towne Center Dr., Suite 400",
                    Surname = "Test",
                    MobilePhone = "+91 1324567891",
                    UsageLocation = "IN",
                    UserPrincipalName = "rukmini@XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
                };

                await handler.CreateUser(requestBody);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}


User created successfully with all the properties:

I modified the code to print ODataErrors so that it will be easy to identity the error.
